# How to convert windows-1250 to utf-16 using c#

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

I am new at c#, I am having a problem with loading XML document which is encoded in windows-1250, and when I want to print the string loaded from that document I dont get chars such as Č,Ć,Š etc. I found out that, before printing, it has to be converted from string to unicode or utf to be able to print it normaly. So my main problem is how to convert a string encoding(from widnows-1250 to utf-16) to be able to print all of the missing letters.

First XML line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
```

Code for loading xml file:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
var items = doc.Descendants("item");
foreach (var item in items)
{
    for (i = 0; i < keyWords.Count; i++ )
    {
        if (item.Value.Contains(keyWords[i])) 
        {
            vestiSaPodudaranjima.Add(item.Value);
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the first line in the xml file.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>

Comment: Then there can only be a problem with your code.  You'll need to show it, just the part where you read the xml file.

Comment: Please show how you're loading the document. Ideally, you should be loading it from the *binary* representation, in which case you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Here is my code i am loading the xml and passing every item node adding it to the list and printing it.
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
        var items = doc.Descendants("item");
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < keyWords.Count; i++ ){
            if(item.Value.Contains(keyWords[i])) 
            {
                vestiSaPodudaranjima.Add(item.Value);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
                         break;
            }}          
        }

Comment: try with `var doc = XDocument.Load(new StreamReader(path, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250")));`

Comment: @JonSkeet i just posted it, its educational project and i need to use loading with xDocument.

Comment: @user3519090: Please put the code in the *question*, not comments. But that should be fine.

Comment: @L.B: No, there should be no need for that. `XDocument.Load(string)` will take care of the encoding.

Comment: @JonSkeet i did it, sorry for that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Just wanted to say there may be a wrong BOM, since  I have seen such xml files.

Comment: L.B: Windows-1250 can't represent a BOM, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: So now that we have a program, what's the problem? It may well just be that your console can't display the characters you're interested in.

Comment: @L.B I tried the line of code that you've suggested, but still having the same problem.

Comment: @gazivoda now can you try it with `Encoding.UTF8`?

Comment: @JonSkeet That might be a problem, is there any way to fix the encoding of console text? I'm planing to display this text later in a Windows form and I'm afraid that I will have the same problem.

Comment: @L.B thanks Encoding with utf-8 worked!

Comment: that means probably that the xml file is incorrectly encoded, differently to what the xml header claims. does this file display in a browser without errors?

Comment: @JonSkeet That was what I meant..

Comment: @ths i think you are right, yes its without errors.